# When using Blender to modify the Pharah model, how do you make simple bodymorph changes using Shapekeys?

Tags: modeling, armature, edit-mode, vertices, shape-keys

I'm new to Blender, but hopefully this question won't require complex program functions. The model's creator says I can alter her body using shapekeys, but I don't know how.

Can someone point me to the right tutorial or explain in simplest terms how to, say, make her thigh less thick or her chest larger. I know this might mess us up her clothing, but I'd just like to make simple/small edits to this fantastic model.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the object data properties (the green triangle) and find the shape keys menu. You can click a shape key, and then drag its Value bar to use it.